# Storing user input data in Internal Memory

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-manifest

I'm tryin to create a simple app that basically is a tracker that keeps track of no. of classes for each subject for a college student. The app is specific to my college timetable. The idea is tht i have 3 activities: main.java, Sublist.java and editcrap.java. The main.java acts as a splash screen and starts the Sublist activity.

In the Sublist activity the user is displayed with a layout displaying (TextView) (Button) (Counter_TextView) horizontally with respect ot each other. There are 7 of these aligned vertically.

When the menu button is clicked: (Edit Subject Parameters) comes up which wen clicked takes the user to editcrap.java activity where the user input is taken in corresponding EditText boxes asking for subject name for each corresponding (TextView) and total number of classes corresponding to (Counter_TextView) in the Sublist activity. On the click of OK button the data is passed bak to Sublist activity for display and manipulation.

Having done this I needed a way to store the data so tht the next time the app is opened it wud retain its previous string and no. of classes values. This is where I'm running into force close errors or No retention of data error. Here is my code...cud someone please tell me wat m doin wrong? I've been struggling for days with this :) I basically need the app to maintain 2 files one containing Strings and the other Numbers that need to be read from and displayed in Sublist.java activity as we i need any changes done by the app user to be reflected unto the original files as well

```
//Sublist.java:


package com.shuaib669.bunkrecord;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Sublist extends Activity{

double[] no_of_classes = new double[7];
int count[]= new int[7];
double cutOff = 0.3;
String[] newText = new String[7];
String[] newNum = new String[7];
String countString = null;
TextView subject[] = new TextView[7];
TextView counter[] = new TextView[7];  //sub11 is counter text view label
Button button[] = new Button[7];     //button1 is the increment button


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Assigning Views to objects.
            subject[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);   
            counter[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter1);
            button[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            subject[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            counter[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter2);
            button[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

            subject[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            counter[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter3);
            button[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

            subject[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            counter[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter4);
            button[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

            subject[4] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            counter[4] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter5);
            button[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

            subject[5] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            counter[5] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter6);
            button[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);

            subject[6] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            counter[6] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter7);
            button[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);

            try {
        // open the file for reading

        DataInputStream in= new DataInputStream(openFileInput(getFilesDir() + "/" + "subject.txt"));
        // if file the available for reading
        if (in!= null) {
          // prepare the file for reading
          String line;
          int x=0;
          // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at the time
          while(in.readLine() != null) {
              // do something with the strings from the file

              line=DataInputStream.readUTF(in);
              subject[x].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
              subject[x].setText(line);
              x+=1;

          }

        }

        // close the file again
        in.close();
      } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();// do something if the myfilename.txt does not exits
      }

    button[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(count[0]>=(no_of_classes[0]*cutOff)){
                counter[0].setTextColor(Color.RED);
                countString = "" +(++count[0]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[0].setText(countString);
            }
            else{
                countString = "" +(++count[0]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[0].setText(countString);
            }


        }
    });

    button[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(count[1]>=(no_of_classes[1]*cutOff)){
                counter[1].setTextColor(Color.RED);
                countString = "" +(++count[1]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[1].setText(countString);
            }
            else{
                countString = "" +(++count[1]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[1].setText(countString);
            }


        }
    });

    button[2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(count[2]>=(no_of_classes[2]*cutOff)){
                counter[2].setTextColor(Color.RED);
                countString = "" +(++count[2]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[2].setText(countString);
            }
            else{
                countString = "" +(++count[2]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[2].setText(countString);
            }


        }
    });

    button[3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(count[3]>=(no_of_classes[3]*cutOff)){
                counter[3].setTextColor(Color.RED);
                countString = "" +(++count[3]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[3].setText(countString);
            }
            else{
                countString = "" +(++count[3]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[3].setText(countString);
            }


        }
    });

    button[4].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(count[4]>=(no_of_classes[4]*cutOff)){
                counter[4].setTextColor(Color.RED);
                countString = "" +(++count[4]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[4].setText(countString);
            }
            else{
                countString = "" +(++count[4]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[4].setText(countString);
            }


        }
    });

    button[5].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(count[5]>=(no_of_classes[5]*cutOff)){
                counter[5].setTextColor(Color.RED);
                countString = "" +(++count[5]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[5].setText(countString);
            }
            else{
                countString = "" +(++count[5]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[5].setText(countString);
            }


        }
    });

    button[6].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(count[6]>=(no_of_classes[6]*cutOff)){
                counter[6].setTextColor(Color.RED);
                countString = "" +(++count[6]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[6].setText(countString);
            }
            else{
                countString = "" +(++count[6]);                 //Convert from int to String to set in your textview::
                counter[6].setText(countString);
            }


        }
    });



}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){      // What the MENU button does.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater castle = getMenuInflater();
    castle.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return(true);
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){  // Opens Options of MENU.

    switch(item.getItemId()){

    case R.id.editcrap: startActivityForResult((new Intent("com.shuaib669.bunkrecord.EDITCRAP")), 1);
                        return(true);
    }

return(false);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
switch(requestCode){

case 1: if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){

        newText = data.getStringArrayExtra("com.shuaib669.bunkrecord.thetext");
        newNum = data.getStringArrayExtra("com.shuaib669.bunkrecord.thenum");

        try {
              // open myfilename.txt for writing
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(openFileOutput(getFilesDir() + "/" + "subject.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));     
        //newNum = data.getIntArrayExtra("com.shuaib669.thenum");
        //for loop to setText in the TextViews of main.xml
        for(int x=0;x<7;x++){



                    subject[x].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    subject[x].setText(newText[x]);
                    // write the contents on mySettings to the file
                    out.writeUTF(newText[x]);

                    try{
                        no_of_classes[x]=Integer.parseInt(newNum[x]);
                        }
                        catch(Exception nfe){
                            nfe.printStackTrace();
                        }         
                  // close the file
                  out.close();
                  }
        }


        catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Data Input Sample", "I/O Error");    //do something if an Exception occurs.
                }



            }


break;
}                                             


}
  }
```

//editcrap.java:

```
package com.shuaib669.bunkrecord;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class editcrap extends Activity{

EditText sub[] = new EditText[7];           //list of subject text edit labels.
Button parambutton1;                                            //OK buttons for edit list.
EditText num[] = new EditText[7];           //list of objects of total no. of classes bunked edit text labels. (boinkers i know)  
String theText[] = new String[7];
String theNum[] = new String[7];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.params);

    sub[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.peditText1);          //pedittext is the parameter menu edit text label
    num[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pnumText1);           //EditText label for takin in total no. of classes for 1 subject

    sub[1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.peditText2);
    num[1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pnumText2);

    sub[2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.peditText3);
    num[2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pnumText3);

    sub[3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.peditText4);
    num[3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pnumText4);

    sub[4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.peditText5);
    num[4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pnumText5);

    sub[5] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.peditText6);
    num[5] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pnumText6);

    sub[6] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.peditText7);
    num[6] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pnumText7);

    parambutton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.parambutton1);    //pbutton1 is the ok button to accept the input.

    parambutton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            for(int x=0;x<7;x++){


                    theText[x] = sub[x].getText().toString();
                    theNum[x]  = num[x].getText().toString();
                    //theNum[x]  = Integer.parseInt(num[x].getText().toString());

                }



            Intent data = new Intent(editcrap.this, Sublist.class);
            data.putExtra("com.shuaib669.bunkrecord.thetext", theText);
            data.putExtra("com.shuaib669.bunkrecord.thenum", theNum);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();

        }
    });


}




}
```

Comment: Why not using shared preferences?

Comment: Why not use a SQLite Database. 
Or you could do a SharedPreference, which seems like exactly what this is.

Comment: ok i'll do that...:)...thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: It just is a much easier then putting them into a file, SharedPreferences can take primitives(int, bool, String) and save them under a name, so you know which ones are which.

Comment: i'm having trouble grasping how Shared Preferences and its related methods work...what exactly are the important steps in saving and retrieving data using shared preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Shared Preferences

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
private static final String PREF_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String PREF_PASSWORD = "password";
```

following code in onCreate() method

```
EtUserName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
EtPassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
```

here you get Preferences value in editText...(if you have previous save Preferences)

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);   
String username = pref.getString(PREF_USERNAME, null);
String password = pref.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, null); 

EtUserName.setText(username);  
EtPassword.setText(password);
```

following code in check box click event...(save Preferences here)

```
             String us,pa;
         us=EtUserName.getText().toString();
         pa=EtPassword.getText().toString();
         SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
                         getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE)
                         .edit()
                         .putString(PREF_USERNAME, us)
                         .putString(PREF_PASSWORD, pa)
                         .commit();
```

for more information [click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).and [here](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html)